# Memtest86 error for all rams in all slots

Tags: memtest86+, dram

Yesterday my computer displayed a memory problem in dimm xx4 in BIOS mode. I ran the memtest86 with Ubuntu live CD and it displayed red error bars for a specific address in memory. I had 4 ddr2 ram sticks so I tested every stick in every slot. In total I ran memtest86 16 times and it displayed red error bars for every ram.
So now how can I know if there is a problem with my motherboard or with my RAM sticks.

- I currently don't have a spare system to test my RAM sticks.

Comment: If every stick failed in every slot, it's most likely either the motherboard, the CPU, or the BIOS settings.

Comment: The system boot up to Windows OS loading screen and then stuck there so the CPU must be okay ?

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: Intel core 2 quad 2.6ghz

Comment: On the Core 2 series, the memory controller is part of the CPU. So a problem with the CPU (or even how well it's sitting in the socket!) would explain your symptoms.

Comment: So then I should check my CPU is properly installed on the socket

Comment: That could be a cause. It's not that likely if you haven't recently reseated your CPU. But I'm just saying that mobo and RAM aren't the only possibilities. I'd check BIOS settings first -- set all RAM voltages and timings to their defaults.

Comment: My USB keyboard was not working in BIOS so for a salutation I found on internet I took out the cell from the motherboard and restarted system and then put it back. So this might has changed the BIOS settings.

Comment: That's a clue. Maybe your BIOS settings for memory voltages and/or timings need to be adjusted.

Comment: Actually, the memory controller wasn't part of the CPU until Sandy Bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what was wrong. My Motherboard was damaged/dead (the repair shop person told me) so I needed to change it and then I bought a new motherboard to use everything normally.
Thanks to @David Schwartz for help.